# Reversing a list in python - Why I failed to return the modified list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

I am working on a function that can reverse the list similar to reverse(). I tried both building a function using slicing and also tried looking old posts and following a similar logic. I understand the logic behind reversing the elements but mechanically I don't understand why the elements remain unreversed at the end of the function.

```
def reverse_list(listofval):
    newlist = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(listofval):
        newlist.append(listofval[len(listofval) - 1 - index])
        index += 1
    return newlist
```

So the above function is just taking the old list (list of val) and keep reading the old list backwards then adding each element in reverse order (last element in old list became first, first became last). But "return newlist" seems to return an unmodified list.

```
def reverse_list(listofval):
    newlist = listofval[::-1]
    return newlist
```

Similarly I have build another function which is more straight forward using slicing and when new list returned, nothing is changed. I guess it must be something wrong with "return newlist" but I am not entirely sure what mistakes I made there.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Could you share a piece of code which calls these functions?

Comment: `print(reverse_list([3,4,5,6]))` should work fine ...

Comment: Both these functions work just fine in that they return a new list that is reversed. The old list will be unaffected. You might have expected them to work like `list.reverse` which reverses an existing list object in-place. Well, they don't, that's why you return a **new** list which you even called exactly that.

Comment: Is there a reason you are reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @KlausD. Possibly for education purposes.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot. Now I get that it basically returns a modified one when it is inside the function (not sure how it is exactly called). And I would need to make some more changes in order for it to change the existing list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse a list in place, you have to modify the passed list:

E.g. by swapping elements:

```
def reverse_list(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) // 2):
        lst[i], lst[len(lst)-1-i] = lst[len(lst)-1-i], lst[i]
```

or slice assignment:

```
def reverse_list(lst):
    lst[:] = lst[::-1]
```

Note that the function no longer returns anything. But the passed list will be reversed after calling it:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> reverse_list(lst)
>>> lst
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to get returned vale is this.

```
def retList():
    list = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        list.append(i)
    return list
a = retList()
print a
```

you can also use global variable for new list before defining the newlist[] in your code

```
global newlist
newlist = []
```

you can also use append left

```
from collections import deque
def reverse_list(listofval):
    global newlist
    newlist = []
    for i in listofval:
        newlist = deque(newlist)
        newlist.appendleft(i)
        print(newlist)
listofval = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
reverse_list(listofval)
print(newlist)
```